# trying to play diffrent audio through the same function javascript by using switch case

Tags: javascript, audio, switch-statement

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />     
  <script>
   var audio;
   function initAudioPlayer() {
    audio = new Audio();
       Eplay = document.getElementById("E");
       Eplay.addEventListener("click", playPause("playE"));

      Aplay = document.getElementById("A");
       Aplay.addEventListener("click", playPause("playA"));
               switch (audio) {
                             case "playE":               
                      audio.src = "sound/Eguitar.mp3";
                                break;
                           case "playA":
                                 audio.src = "sound/A-guitar.mp3";
                               break;                                
                 default:  audio.src = "sound/highE-guitar.mp3";
                         } 
                 function playPause() {

                     if (audio.paused) {

                         audio.play();

                     } else {
                         audio.pause();    
                     }
             }
           }
             window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>                  
        <div class="guitar">
        <button id="E">E </button>
       <button id="A">A </button>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>

> Blockquote
```

can someone please tell me what am i doiing wrong?
i'm tryng to make a guitar tuner
trying to change the audio.src in diffrent cases.

Comment: Reading how [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) works might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:Also your switch was not taking any value,and your function playPause() pass parameter to use.

```js
var audio,Eplay,Aplay;
   function initAudioPlayer() {
    
       Eplay = document.getElementById("E");
       Eplay.addEventListener("click", function(){playPause("playE");});//adding callback

      Aplay = document.getElementById("A");
       Aplay.addEventListener("click",function(){ playPause("playA");});//adding callback
            
               
           }

   function playPause(audio1) {//passing parameter here
    alert(audio1);
    audio = new Audio();
    switch (audio1) {
       case "playE":               
audio.src = "sound/Eguitar.mp3";
          break;
     case "playA":
           audio.src = "sound/A-guitar.mp3";
         break;                                
default:  audio.src = "sound/highE-guitar.mp3";
   } 
     if (audio.paused) {

         audio.play();

     } else {
         audio.pause();    
     }
}
             window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />     
  <script>
   
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>                  
        <div class="guitar">
        <button id="E">E </button>
       <button id="A">A </button>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, now it works but for some reason the audio won't pause

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement should be in the function that gets called from the click event on your Eplay and Aplay elements.

In your event handler function call, you are passing in the string "playE" or "playA", so you will need to add that parameter to the function definition so you can use it. Try something like this:

```
function playPause(note) {
    switch(note) {
        case "playE" : 
            // Set audio src...
        break;
        case "playA" : 
            // Set audio src...
        break;
    }
    // Play or pause audio
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your playPause function needs an argument in its signature. Like, `function playPause(chord) {`

2) Your `switch (audio)` block will only run once, on page load. You want it to run every time the user clicks a play/pause button, right?

Move that block to the `playPause()` function.

3) Fix the variable used for the `switch` block.

See the code below with the following issues fixed:

```
var audio;
function initAudioPlayer() {
    audio = new Audio();
    Eplay = document.getElementById("E");
    Eplay.addEventListener("click", playPause("playE"));
    Aplay = document.getElementById("A");
    Aplay.addEventListener("click", playPause("playA"));
    function playPause(chord) {
         switch (chord) {
            case "playE":               
              audio.src = "sound/Eguitar.mp3";
              break;
            case "playA":
              audio.src = "sound/A-guitar.mp3";
              break;                                
            default:  audio.src = "sound/highE-guitar.mp3";
         } 
         if (audio.paused) {

             audio.play();

         } else {
             audio.pause();    
         }
    }   
}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```