# whats wrong with this code trying to add sound on buttons with class name .drum in html

Tags: javascript, queryselector

```js
var drumlenght = querySelectorAll(".drum").length

for (var i = 0; i < drumlenght; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("hi")
  });
}
```

whats wrong with this code trying to add sound on buttons with class name `.drum` in html.

Comment: You need to write `document.querySelectorAll` when you grab the length.

Comment: You can find answer here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62033045/i-have-7-drums-display-each-drum-is-supposed-to-make-a-different-sound-when-you
may be duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

This is the right structure of your code :)

- learn more [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

### tips

- avoid using `var`
- when you start javaScript project line 1 you can apply `use strict` mode on,

```
'use strict';

let drumlenght = document.querySelectorAll('.drum').length;

for (let i = 0; i < drumlenght; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.drum')[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('hi');
  });
}
```